# How can I detect newly added files in a distant folder over the web in R?

Tags: r, http, automation, download, detection

How can I write an R script running on a server, that would detect whenever a new CSV file (or other specific format) is added in a distant folder over the web, and download it automatically ?

Example folder: https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/

As soon as a new CSV file is added in this folder, I want to download it right away to process it locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the OP was looking for an "event listener" to monitor for changes on the file server, but *some* message has to be sent from the distant computer to notify your computer of the change. If you have no control over the file server, the only way to get it to send you a message is by first sending it a request. This means the only general "event listener" available is one that works by intermittently polling the server.

Depending on how frequently you poll, this should work perfectly well as an event listener. As an analogy, many species of bats hunt by sending out intermittent pulses of ultrasound and listening for the response. This is a form of intermittent polling that works well enough to keep them alive.

This does mean having to have some sort of software running in the background on your own computer. Your two options here are to use scheduling to run the R script intermittently, or to run an R script in the background that loops with a pause in between polls.

It appears from comments that the OP only wants to download any *new* files added to the server, but not to create copies of existing files when the program is first run. This means that a file has to be stored locally listing the contents of the ftp directory the last time it was checked, then comparing this to the current contents of the ftp directory, and downloading any new files as well as updating the content record.

Here's a function that does just that. The first time you run it, it will create a new local directory named after the hosting url and a `.csv` file with a listing of the directory at that point. Subsequent calls to the function after this will compare the contents of the local and remote directories and download any new files:

```
local_mirror <- function(url, root_dir = path.expand("~/"), silent = FALSE)
{
  if(substring(root_dir, nchar(root_dir), nchar(root_dir)) != "/")
    root_dir <- paste0(root_dir, "/")
  content <- rvest::html_nodes(xml2::read_html(url), "a")
  links <- rvest::html_attr(content, "href")
  links <- grep("/", links, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
  rel_path <- strsplit(url, "//")[[1]][2]
  mirror_path <- paste0(root_dir, rel_path)
  if(!dir.exists(mirror_path))
  {
    build_path <- root_dir
    for(i in strsplit(rel_path, "/")[[1]])
    {
      build_path <- paste0(build_path, i, "/")
      dir.create(build_path)
    }
    write.csv(links, paste0(mirror_path, ".mirrordat.csv"))
  }
  records <- read.csv(paste0(mirror_path, ".mirrordat.csv"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  current_files <- records$x
  n_updated <- 0
  if(!silent) cat("Updating files - please wait")
  for(i in seq_along(links))
  {
    if(!(links[i] %in% current_files))
    {
      download.file(paste0(url, links[i]), paste0(mirror_path, links[i]))
      n_updated <- n_updated + 1
    }
  }
  if(!silent) message(paste("Downloaded", n_updated, "files"))
  write.csv(links, paste0(mirror_path, ".mirrordat.csv"))
}
```

To run the function in your case, you would just run:

```
local_mirror("https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/")
```

and to run it as a constant "event monitor" in the background, you would place it inside a looping function like this:

```
listen_for_changes <- function(url, poll_every = 5, silent = TRUE)
{
  repeat
  {
    local_mirror(url, silent = silent)
    Sys.sleep(poll_every)
  }
}
```

Which you would just run with:

```
listen_for_changes("https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/")
```

Comment: @alp In terms of "listening" to the server, some sort of message has to be exchanged between the remote server and your PC to notify you of a change. If you have no control over the remote server, then this message has to be prompted by a request from you, so your only option is intermittent polling. You don't have to run the same function again and again - you could leave a single function running that repeats my function in a loop in the background with a pause in between requests. This effectively _is_ an event listener - you have to have _something_ running that does the listening.

Comment: @alp with regards to the massive downloads, this function only replicates the folder you point it to, not the subdirectories, so it won't normally try to download terabytes of data. You could easily modify it to only get the .csv files and look for new .csv files. Alternatively, it could just store the names of the distant files without copying them, but download any new files. Let me know if this would be helpful and I can modify the answer.

Comment: @alp please see my update. I have changed it to save just the names of existing files but to download any new ones when they appear. I have also included an example of running it in a continuous loop to act as an event listener. The answer also now includes a discussion of why intermittent polling is the only option here and why it's not as bad as it first sounds.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem a while ago, and I wrote a (somewhat) comprehensive function called `repchkdl()` for this purpose, which I've now bundled into a small `R` package.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/vragh/repchkdl) to its Github repo.

It is similar to the solution suggested by @Allan Cameron in many ways, and provides additional options for fine tuning how the remote URL is scanned (manual/auto options), how files are downloaded (e.g., filtering with regular expressions), and iteration frequency + limits (e.g., scan every 2 minutes, repeat that twice in total and exit thereafter) among other things.

Example usage:

```
test <- repchkdl(inpurl = "ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload/", 
                 inpregex = ".txt$", autoscan = "y", autodl = "y", inpwait = 10,
                 scanlim = 2)
```

This will automatically download (`autoscan = "y"`, `autodl = "y"`) all files ending with `.txt` (`inpregex = ".txt$"`) from the URL `ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload/`, and check for updates every 10 seconds (`inpwait = 10`). The function will re-check twice (`scanlim = 2`) before exiting. A vector of the filenames will be saved to the object `test`.

**Edit:**
The package has been completely overhauled, and has additional features including silent mode operation. The repo location remains the [same](https://github.com/vragh/repchkdl). The function invocation has changed slightly as follows (as an example):

```
test <- repchkdl(url = "ftp://ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us/pub/usf/", 
                 usr = "anonymous", pwd = "exampleuser@example.com",
                 scanlim = 2, wait = 2, verbosity = TRUE)

head(test)
#                      flinks   fsizes dlstats
# 1        SWFWMD_May2020.txt 25321197 SUCCESS
# 2 USF_SCADA_AM_20200517.csv  2322041 SUCCESS
# 3 USF_SCADA_AM_20200518.csv  2321932 SUCCESS
# 4 USF_SCADA_AM_20200519.csv  2323118 SUCCESS
# 5 USF_SCADA_AM_20200520.csv  2322689 SUCCESS
# 6 USF_SCADA_AM_20200521.csv  2322243 SUCCESS
```

Comment: @alp The package has been overhauled completely. Give it a try.